# Add a new folder to Ruby on Rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm utilizing a bootstrap template and it requires a plugin for a revolution slider. I'm used to check the source code of the template and remove individual JS and CSS files it requires and place them in the asset pipeline. Is there any way to import into the asset pipeline the entire plugin folder with all of its files?

Here is a picture of what the folder contains:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've added the rs-plugin to the assets portion of my app:

[image: update]

In `application.rb` I've added the following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("assets", "rs-plugin-5")
```

In `assets/javascripts/application.js` I've added the following:

```
//= require rs-plugin-5/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min
//= require rs-plugin-5/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: update 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by adding next line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('/path/to/folder')
```

Comment: I am going to try it out in a bit how would I reference it in the asset pipeline?

Comment: couldn't find file 'js/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min' with type 'application/javascript' this is what I am getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152977/discussion-between-jermaine-subia-and-danil-speransky).